# Entity Framework code first, Not working anymore for Console Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

This code is based on Microsoft Site which is in here [enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx)

It was working before in my Visual Studio 2013 and I know for 2015 as well, But for some reason, I updated my Visual Studio 2015 to add new Features like Xamarin and Emulator VS. It also updated some of the components of Visual Stuidio 2015 which replaces the icon of the launcher itself to Violet border and White logo of VS.

Now this simple code is pretty straight forward with no DB connection which by default the EF will handle. I have SQL server 2012 by the way.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new BloggingContext())
        {
            // Create and save a new Blog 
            Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Blog: ");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();

            var blog = new Blog { Name = name };
            db.Blogs.Add(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();

            // Display all Blogs from the database 
            var query = from b in db.Blogs
                        orderby b.Name
                        select b;

            Console.WriteLine("All blogs in the database:");
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
}
```

As you can see, this is very simple db context Without any migrations or anything, not even an MVC asp app that requires config file for connection string.

This application does not return any Build Error, Syntax Error or even Runtime error.

It simply runs, but no Database generated. There fore no results. The query itself is not returning any null value.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Where exactly you're excepting DB to be created? You haven't provided any connection string, so EF will use its defaults to determine required DB location. It tries SQLExpress instance first and then LocalDB if there is no SQL instance present.

Comment: As you said, it should be in the SQL server with the base name that is supplied in the db context class. But there is no Database Created in the SQL server. And if I create a new Database from the Template, I got an error something about the Database that I have doesn't supported in the SQL Server 2012 when I attached it, do you think that could be the problem? If it is, How could I use the old LocalDB even if I have SQL server instance?

Comment: Probably the most easiest way for you to force EF to work with exact DB - is to specify connection string explicitly in `BloggingContext` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

By default, VS uses SQL Express for the data as documented in the

**Where’s My Data?**

> By convention DbContext has created a database for you.
>
> If a local SQL Express instance is available (installed by default
> with Visual Studio 2010) then Code First has created the database on
> that instance
>
> If SQL Express isn’t available then Code First will try
> and use LocalDb (installed by default with Visual Studio 2012)
>
> The
> database is named after the fully qualified name of the derived
> context, in our case that is
> CodeFirstNewDatabaseSample.BloggingContext

Answer (score 0):

You have to inform EF where You expecting the database to be created. To do this You need to pass `ConnectionString` name to base constructor of `DbContext`. Please do following steps to achieve this:

A. Change Your `DbContext` like this:

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
    {

    public BloggingContext ()
            : base("ConnectionString")
        {}

        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

B. In Your `App.config` file in section: `configuration` add:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SQLSERVERINSTANCE;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User ID=USERID;Password=PASS;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Please note that name in `base("ConnectionString")` has to correspond to name from config line `name="ConnectionString"`